# Using browser drivers while using tortoise subversion in jenkins

Tags: svn, maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am using windows xp, maven3.0.4, jenkins, tortoise subversion

I am using tortoise subversion where I post my code and use it to run tests in slave machines from the master(all machines are windows xp). I want to run the test at a time in different slaves and different browsers. In order to run in different slaves I pasted the browserdrivers in the same path in all the machines and then executed the test. Here's my question: Is there any better option for this??

Comment: What does subversion and TortoiseSVN have to do with tests?

Comment: i used to post the code so that i dont need to hav the code in every machines when running the same from master in different slaves by one trigger

Comment: I mean,... can I ask something, I know it may be stupidity.. can I post an exe file in TortoiseSVN and effectively make it run in different machines??? That will be a solution :(

Comment: @sree: Effectively you can by writing a [hook-script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks), which runs a committed exe-file, however I highly doubt that SVN is intended to be used that way.